# Como usar LIKE com o knex/postgres?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Estou precisando realizar uma consulta via knex, para um banco postgres, usando a tag LIKE conforme abaixo:

```
function getPessoas(nomeIncompleto){

return db('tab_pessoas').where('nomePessoa', 'like', '%nomeIncompleto%')

}
```

A consulta funciona, mas a variável recebida na função, não é reconhecida, ou melhor, 'nomeIncompleto' é identicado no seu valor literal e não da variável recebida na função.

Desde já agradeço, abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Amigos, eu mesmo irei a responder para tentar ajudar alguém com o mesmo problema algum dia.
Para o problema acima, posso indicar 2 soluções, podem haver outras:

Na PRIMEIRA resolvi usando interpolação de strings e tratando o argumento da função caso não fosse informado. Para ficar melhor ainda, poderia trocar o LIKE por ILIKE (não case sensitive)

```
function getPessoas(nomeIncompleto){
const n = nomeIncompleto ? nomeIncompleto : ''
return db('tab_pessoas').where('nomePessoa', 'like', `%${n}%`)
}
```

Na SEGUNDA forma, substitui o LIKE por um operador regex do postgres. Também fui obrigado a tratar o argumento da função e utilizei crase (interpolação).

```
function getPessoas(nomeIncompleto){
    const n = nomeIncompleto ? nomeIncompleto : ''
    return db('tab_pessoas').where('nomePessoa', '~*', `.*${n}`)
    }
```

Caso o procedimento de responder eu mesmo a uma pergunta minha seja errado, me desculpem os moderadores. Farei as alterações necessárias caso seja pedido.